# Change Firebase Security Rules with a Google Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I've been going through this [new little series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRj0RRAxYX8) on Firebase Cloud Functions for monitoring and ultimately shutting down your firebase project when spending reaches a limit.

The solution provided is pretty hard core.  I had an idea, and I don't think this exists, but wanted to put it out there in case someone has found a solution or one comes along in the future.

Is there a way to change/add/revert to a previous version of your firebase security rules using a cloud function?  I'm thinking that this could be a more effective and nuanced kill switch for billing issues.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have spent a few days trying to figure out how costs are calculated to try and figure out how to write the trigger. The google docs come with a warning that billing doesn't shut down for a few days, so the kill switch in the final episode of the you tube series isn't enough on its own. There is a cap of 10 security rules looking for  exists checks - and so far, i think ill use that whole allowance writing the checks that would turn off the system. Did you find anything useful when you were thinking about how to approach this?

Comment: I implemented the slack alerts as detailed in the firebase video, and set my warnings to be pretty regular.  Haven't gotten back to it.  What I was thinking was to lock down the database by prohibiting all reads and writes in the rules.  You could also design it in a nuanced way by locking down only admin traffic, only reads...whatever suits you.  I did not investigate how to do that yet, but Doug has some links below that could be useful.  Haven't read them.

Answer (score 1):

The documented ways to [deploy security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy) outside of the Firebase console are:

- [Using the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#use_the)
- [Using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy)

You can certainly try to use the Admin SDK in a Cloud Function.  It's up to you to figure out how to use it to implement whatever you're trying to achieve.